# Passing data from ViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, textview, segue

I have setup a segue to another controller and I am trying to pass some text from a textView to the new controller. When I run the program I keep getting an error: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

I know the value I am passing is NOT nil...See my segue code below

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "getReflection" {
                if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ReflectionViewController {
                    destinationVC.reflectionTextBox.text = self.reflectionTextBox.text
//Crashes on the above expression???
                    destinationVC.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your destination ViewController's view has not been instantiated at the time of preparation, so IBOutlet bindings have not occurred.

In this case, if `destinationVC.reflectionTextBox` is defined as `@IBOutlet weak var reflectionTextBox: UITextView!`, the crash occurs when the `!` optional unwrapping tries to return the reference to the `reflectionTextBox` which is not yet bound. `prepareSegue` should be used for passing data to the destination view controller, the destination view controller can then look for these parameters in its `viewDidLoad` function to utilize them in any UI components.

Comment: Hi Kevin, The weak var issue makes sense, but can you give an example of how to pass a variable in the prepare for segue function? how would viewDIdLoad access them? or maybe I can just declare a strong variable in the receiving controller and then use it to populate the text box?

Comment: Thank you...The strong variable works...no need for an example

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the way I would go about it for most use cases. It can even be weak, as the underlying issue here wasn't variable reference counting. Its just that IB bindings aren't initialized until later on in the lifecycle. Glad this helped out, and thanks for accepting the answer!